# Error: ‘void*’ is not a pointer-to-object type error while dynamically opening multiple shared libraries

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, casting, shared-libraries

I need to open multiple shared libraries at run time. I don't know their number(count), so I am using dynamic memory allocation:

```
void* handle= new void* [n]; // n refers to number of handles
handle[0] = dlopen("./fileN.so", RTLD_LAZY); // doesn't work : Error: ‘void*’ is not a pointer-to-object type
```

However if I do static allocation, it works-

```
void* handle[10];
handle[0] = dlopen("./file0.so", RTLD_LAZY); // works
```

Why is that when I am dynamically accessing the handle, I am getting error? and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an extra level of indirection. A pointer to a pointer:

```
void** handle= new void* [n];
     ^
```

Your code would be invalid on another type:

```
int* handle= new int* [n]; // error assigning int** to int*
```

But it works with `void*` as `void*` can point to `void**`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `handle` as `void**`, not `void*`.